# Right way to retrieve column from database for join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I have has_many through association for User, Prog and Enrollment models. Idea is that User can add a Prog to his profile list and Prog can decline or accept request from Users.

This is how accept method looks like:

enrollments#accept

```
def accept
  @enrollment = Enrollment.find_by_user_id(params[:id])
  @enrollment.status = "accepted"
  @enrollment.save!
  ....
end
```

I undestand why this is not right and if I understand correctly in accept method Enrollment must get user.id and prog.id to retrieve data from database. So, user.id is passed with link_to but how do I show prog.id to help Enrollment find column I need?

```
  <% @prog.users.each do |user| %> 
  <%= link_to "#{user.email} accept", controller: "/enrollments", action: "accept", id: user.id, method: "post" %>
  <% end %>
```

My guess that something basic is missed if that's true than let me know what shall I focus on to make it work.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to pass two parameters (for user_id and prog_id) to the link and find the enrollment with these two parameters. 
View:

```
<%= link_to "#{user.email} accept", controller: :enrollments, action: :accept, user_id: user.id, prog_id: @prog.id, method: :post %>
```

And in controller:

```
@enrollment = Enrollment.find_by_user_id_and_prog_id params[:user_id], params[:prog_id]
```